# Drop the columns "id" and "Unnamed: 0" from axis 1 using the method drop()

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing this:

```
df.drop(['id','Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

My syntax is correct but it is not working.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you can explain *how* it is not working...?

Answer (score 0):

The "Unnamed: 0" column usually happens when you read a file which contains the row's indexes, however, the corresponding column name is empty. Suppose you have the following ".csv" file:

```
,id,A,B
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
```

Note that the above file starts the first line with a comma, which will generate the undesired "Unnamed: 0" column. To read from the file and build your DataFrame without this issue, try setting index_col=0:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', index_col=0)
print(df)
```

The result will be:

```
  id  A  B
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

now let's drop the 'id' column:

```
df.drop(['id'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

and the result is:

```
   B  C
0  2  3
1  5  6
2  8  9
```